# Proof of Motzkin's transposition theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

I am having difficulty with the proof of Motkin's transposition theorem:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices and let $b$ and $c$ be column vectors. Then there exists a vector $x$ with $Ax < b$ and $Bx ≤ c$, if and only if
>
> for all row vectors $y, z ≥ 0$:
>
> (i) if $yA + zB = 0$ then $yb + zc ≥ 0$; and
>
> (ii) if $yA + zB = 0$ and $y ≠ 0$ then $yb + zc > 0$.

It is clear that the conditions (i) and (ii) are necessary. It is also clear from Farkas' lemma that the conditions are sufficient for $Ax ≤ b$ and $Bx ≤ c$.

Can anyone explain why the conditions are sufficient for the strict inequality $Ax < b$?

The textbook I am reading explains that "Condition (ii) implies that for each inequality $a_ix ≤ b_i$ in the system $Ax ≤ b$ there are no $y, z ≥ 0$ with $yA + zB = -a_i$ and $yb + zc ≤ -b_i$. By Farkas' Lemma, this is equivalent to: for each inequality $a_ix ≤ b_i$ in $Ax ≤ b$ there is a vector $x^i$ with $Ax^i ≤ b$, $Bx^i ≤ c$ and $a_ix^i < b_i$."

It's not apparent to me how the second sentence follows from the first.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for the tip. Will do.

Comment: @DL1 which textbook are you using

Comment: @Gab It's Theory of Linear and Integer Programming by Alexander Schrijver. A pdf be found online here: https://promathmedia.files.wordpress.com/2013/10/alexander_schrijver_theory_of_linear_and_integerbookfi-org.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I have also read this book and I will give a proof of mine. But I think it's too complicated and not as concise as what the author said. So if someone has a more concise and direct proof, please show your answer with us.

I only give my proof for the second sentence. Consider the inverse proposition of the first sentence. $\exists\ y,z\geq 0, yA+zB=-a_i\text{ and }yb+zc\leq -b_i$. From Farkas' lemma, this is equivalent to: $\forall\ x\gtrless 0, t\geq 0\text{ with }Ax+bt\geq 0,Bx+ct\geq 0, \text{ there must be }-a_ix-b_it\geq 0$. So for the original proposition of the first sentence, it is equivalent to $\exists\ x\gtrless 0, t\geq 0\text{ satisfied }Ax+bt\geq 0,Bx+ct\geq 0,-a_ix-b_it<0$.

Then we need to prove there must be a $(x,t)$ pair with $t>0$ for each inequality in the system $Ax\leq b$. We prove by contradiction. We assume there is no $(x,t)$ pair with $t>0$ satisfied $Ax+bt\geq 0,Bx+ct\geq 0,-a_ix-b_it<0$, i.e. $\forall\ x\gtrless 0, t>0$ either $Ax+bt<0,Bx+ct<0$ or $Ax+bt\geq 0,Bx+ct\geq 0,-a_ix-b_it\geq 0$. For the first case, we get $A(-\frac 1tx)>b,B(-\frac 1tx)>c$; For the second case, we get $A(-\frac 1tx)\leq b,B(-\frac 1tx)\leq c,a_i(-\frac 1tx)\geq b_i$, which means the certain inequality in $Ax\leq b$ get active. Since $x\gtrless 0,\ -\frac 1tx\gtrless 0$. So we know $\forall x\gtrless 0$, either $x$ is infeasible for the system $Ax\leq b,Bx\leq c$, or $x$ is feasible and makes at least one inequality in $Ax\leq b$ active. For general case, we know the system $Ax\leq b,Bx\leq c$ is a polyhedron and can be decomposed as the addition of a polytope and a polyhedral cone, so there must be some feasible solutions maked no inequality sctive. Also if we always have $Ax=b$, then condition (ii) can't be always right. So we get the contradiction.

So there must be a $(x,t), t>0$ pair satisfied $Ax+bt\geq 0,Bx+ct\geq 0,-a_ix-b_it<0$, we get $A(-\frac 1tx)\leq b,B(-\frac 1tx)\leq c,a_i(-\frac1tx)<b_i$. Then by following the proof of the textbook, we can prove the original theorem.